# Getter setter method for image type?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, javabeans

How could an image type be used in bean. My bean reflects a profile of a person which has a set of string and their profile picture. I am not sure about the type for the getter and setter methods for the image type data.

```
    private Image image; //what replaces Image? 

 public void setImage(TYPE image) {
    this.image= image;
   }

   public TYPE getImage() {
    return Image;
}
```

please note I want to store displayable object, and using the get method in another class to display the image.

Comment: It's up to you. What do you want to store in this bean? The path of the image? A displayable image object? The raw bytes of the image file? The ID of the row containing the image in your database? What will you do with the image stored in this bean in the application? Where does the image come from?

Comment: I want to store the displayable image object so that when the get method is called in another class, an image is displayed :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `Icon` (or `ImageIcon`). To display an image in a swing app, the easiest way is to use a `JLabel` and construct it with an `Icon`. So that's probably what your bean should contain.